# Assigning variables from feature class/shapefile?

Tags: arcpy, numpy

I'm new at Python but I want to either assign or reference specific values from a feature class of earthquake data in a Python script to be used in a custom function. I've tried using Feature Class To NumPy Array as the following:

`eq = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray('wells_eq', fields)`

When I print the result, this is what is returned:

`>>> print eq
[(41.144, -114.872, 1.6, 1.6, 1.9, 10.0, 21.0, 212.0, 71.0)]`

I want to assign a variable, such as strike1 and dip1. I tried

`strike1 = eq[5]` but got

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`

As a check for indexing, I tried

`>>> print eq[0]
(41.144, -114.872, 1.6, 1.6, 1.9, 10.0, 21.0, 212.0, 71.0)`

So my question is, how can either I make individual variables based on the values in the feature class, or reference those values to be used in a custom function? Or should I try a different approach altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list has only one item in it which is a tuple.

To see the sixth item in that tuple use:

```
print eq[0][5]
```

I think of this as being that I am printing the 6th item in the first item in the list object called eq.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. So the first bracket calls the tuple and the second calls the desired element within the tuple?

Comment: Yes - I think of it as being that I am printing the 6th item in the first item in the list object called `eq`.

Answer (score 1):

```
eq = (41.144, -114.872, 1.6, 1.6, 1.9, 10.0, 21.0, 212.0, 71.0)

strike1, dip1, ht1, wt1, ... ,lt1 = eq
```

Be sure to make your number of variables be almost close to the number of items in 'eq'

```
print(strike1)
```

to see 41.144